How to import custom images into the Img.ly SDK in a React.js project?
I'm working on a React.js project that uses the Img.ly SDK (CreativeEditor SDK) for image editing. I want to allow users to upload their custom images and have them appear in the editor's upload section, so they can be selected for editing.
image - 1
I've successfully implemented an API that uploads the user's images to the server, but after a page refresh, the images disappear from the editor's upload section. I would like to fetch the uploaded images and display them in the Img.ly SDK's media library, so they persist across sessions.
image - 2
image - 3
enter image description here
I've gone through the SDK documentation, but I couldn't find a detailed example addressing this specific use case. Could anyone provide guidance or code examples to:

Handle the upload process for custom images within the Img.ly SDK.
Ensure the uploaded images are displayed in the SDK's media library for editing.
Persist the uploaded images across sessions, so they are available after a page refresh.

What I Tried:
I’ve implemented an API that uploads the user’s images to a server, and I can successfully upload images and see them in the Img.ly editor. However, after refreshing the page, the uploaded images disappear from the editor’s upload section.
What I Expected:
I expected the images to persist after refreshing the page, automatically fetching and displaying them in the Img.ly SDK's media library.
What Happened:
The images do not persist, and the media library is empty after a refresh. I’m looking for a way to load the previously uploaded images into the media library whenever the editor is initialized.
